# Problem with typecast in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe

I try to do list of procedures this way:

```
type

TProc = procedure of object;

TMyClass=class
private
fList:Tlist;
function getItem(index:integer):TProc;
{....}
public
{....}
end;
implementation
{....}
function TMyClass.getItem(index: Integer): TProc;
begin
 Result:= TProc(flist[index]);// <--- error is here!
end;
{....}
end.
```

and get error:

> E2089 Invalid typecast

How can I fix it?
As I see, I can make a fake class with only one property `Proc:TProc;` and make list of it. But I feel that it's a bad way, isn't it?

PS: project have to be delphi-7-compatible.

Comment: Why are you using XE if you want the code to work in D7. That's going to cause you grief.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typecast is invalid because you can not fit a method pointer to a pointer, a method pointer is in fact two pointers first being the address of the method and the second being a reference to the object that the method belongs. See [Procedural Types](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/proceduraltypes_xml.html) in the documentation. This will not work in any version of Delphi.

Answer (score 4):

Sertac has explained why your code doesn't work.  In order to implement a list of such things in Delphi 7 you can do something like this.

```
type
  PProc = ^TProc;
  TProc = procedure of object;

  TProcList = class(TList)
  private
    FList: TList;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): TProc;
    procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; const Item: TProc);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Count: Integer read GetCount;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: TProc read GetItem write SetItem; default;
    function Add(const Item: TProc): Integer;
    procedure Delete(Index: Integer);
    procedure Clear;
  end;

type
  TProcListContainer = class(TList)
  protected
    procedure Notify(Ptr: Pointer; Action: TListNotification); override;
  end;

procedure TProcListContainer.Notify(Ptr: Pointer; Action: TListNotification);
begin
  inherited;
  case Action of
  lnDeleted:
    Dispose(Ptr);
  end;
end;

constructor TProcList.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FList := TProcListContainer.Create;
end;

destructor TProcList.Destroy;
begin
  FList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TProcList.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FList.Count;
end;

function TProcList.GetItem(Index: Integer): TProc;
begin
  Result := PProc(FList[Index])^;
end;

procedure TProcList.SetItem(Index: Integer; const Item: TProc);
var
  P: PProc;
begin
  New(P);
  P^ := Item;
  FList[Index] := P;
end;

function TProcList.Add(const Item: TProc): Integer;
var
  P: PProc;
begin
  New(P);
  P^ := Item;
  Result := FList.Add(P);
end;

procedure TProcList.Delete(Index: Integer);
begin
  FList.Delete(Index);
end;

procedure TProcList.Clear;
begin
  FList.Clear;
end;
```

**Disclaimer:** completely untested code, use at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you, your variant is very interesting. But it seems that I'll use the fake-class because it fits better into the overall concept